# nginx on mac won't run php

Tags: nginx, php

just brewed nginx and php-fpm on my mac (10.9). I used this tutorial:
http://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mac/osx-brew-php-mysql-nginx/

So but when I set up my first "server"-blog in ngix conf, the php-files always will be downloaded, and I don't find any solutions on google.

Here's my conf:

```
http {
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/pma.dev.conf;
    include /usr/local/Sites/localsites.conf;   
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    server {
        server_name  pma.dev;
        listen       pma.dev:9090;

        location / {
            root   /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin;
            index  index.php;
    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Offtopic. This is a server configuration issue. Try serverfault, or perhaps superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `fastcgi_pass` directive to tell nginx where your FPM server is running. Eg. `fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;` if you're running it on port 9000.

Comment: I did use this but then it says there is something listening on "9000" So I got this: `netstat -anp tcp | grep 9000` ->
`tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9000         *.*                    LISTEN     `

Comment: Read the contents of `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew-php.josegonzalez.php54.plist` to see which port your FPM is configured to listen on, then use that port in the `fastcgi_pass` setting.